# Response header in websocket handshake C# .NET 4.7.2?

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, websocket-sharp

I am using the websockets with C# .NET 4.7.2., specifically the ClientWebSocket class within the System.Net.Websockets namespace.

Is there any way to read the response headers during the handshake ?

In Java or Swift you can get the response headers during the handshake by overriding the following method of the websocket:

```
public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
    String responseHeader = serverHandshake.getFieldValue("RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME");
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, webSocketTask: URLSessionWebSocketTask, didOpenWithProtocol protocolName: String?){
        
        let response: URLResponse = webSocketTask.response!
        if let httpUrlResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        {
            let allHeaderFields: [AnyHashable: Any] = httpUrlResponse.allHeaderFields
            let headerField = allHeaderFields["RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME"]! as! String
        }
        
    }
```

Is there anything similar in C# ?

Comment: I believe you have to write a c# class that inherits the WebSocket.  Then from inside the class you can get access to the header.  The managed c# library make it impossible to get without an inherited class since the header is private.

Comment: Tried writing the C# class that inherits the WebSocket, however it is still unclear were the headers would be. Could they be somewhere inside the SubProtocol property ? Tried also another library https://sta.github.io/websocket-sharp/, however there are no response headers during the handshake. Please don't tell me it is not possible that I have to implement the Websocket from scratch.

Comment: Any source code sample would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Microsoft has a webpage Reference Source which contains the source.  Here is link to Websocket : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocket.cs,714805d98f2c5dd2

Comment: Thanks for the link. Still not clear how to reach the response headers during the handshake. Luckily there is another solution. Add some logic on the backend in the OnMessage event handler and return the required header. This should have been done in the OnOpen though. Can't believe that Microsoft does not have this possibility as in Java or Swift.